# How to use PushpinOffset enumeration in Bing Maps to align Pushpins to coordinate?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

I am trying to add Pushpins to Bing Maps using Windows Store (WinRT) API.

In the documentations I see that there is an Enumeration called PushpinOffset but I just cannot find how and where to apply it. I had a look on the Pushpin as well as the Map instance and I couldn't find it any properties where I should add this enum.

This is most likely a rather trivial issue but I would be grateful if someone could show me how to use [PushpinOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn305997.aspx) enumerations using C#/Bing Maps Store API.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MapLayer.SetPositionAnchor method instead to offset the position of your pushpin. For example:

```
MapLayer.SetPositionAnchor(pin, new Point(10,10))
```